# Possible to use Jinja2 expressions in role vars file

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a Jinja2 {% if %} expression inside a vars file?

So say I have:

```
az:
 az1: foo
 az2: bar
 az3: foobar

{% if az == az['az1'] %}
  floating_ip_pool = bar
{% endif %}
```

Basically, I'm trying to avoid having to set these variables each time since they'll always be based on the az.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not valid syntax. A vars file must first be parsed as a YAML document, and introducing that Jinja syntax results in something that is no longer valid YAML.

You can do something like this instead:

```
az:
 az1: foo
 az2: bar
 az3: foobar

floating_ip_pool: "{% if target_az == az['az1'] %}bar{% endif %}"
```